# How can I express a sum of n variables where the output is bounded between two scalars?

Tags: summation

How can I express a sum of n variables where the output is bounded between 0 and 10?

e.g.

```
x = n1 + n2 + n3 = 12 
12 > 10 
= 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example like this (I changed the notation a bit, because there would otherwise be two different $n$'s):
$$
X = \max \left\{ \min \left\{ a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n~, ~ 10\right\}~, ~0 \right\}
$$